# Do Swiss place names have a comma before the canton, or is the canton in parentheses?

Tags: commas, geography

Is it "Bern, BE" like American place names, or "Bern (BE)" or "Bern BE"?

Or does it depend on whether it's American/Canadian/British/Australian/etc. English, or perhaps simply on style guides like AP, MLA, etc.?

Or does it depend on the dominant language of the place in Switzerland?  (E.g. a French town would follow Swiss French rules and a German town would follow Swiss German rules, even though this is all in English.)

Bonus: Are there other places in the world where, even in English, we shouldn't follow the "[city], [state/province/canton/region]" convention used in e.g. Canada and the US?

Answer (score 2):

The larger cities are rarely qualified by their canton, state, county etc. And though New York, New York has been immortalised, Zurich, Zurich comes across as slightly ludicrous. And the smaller settlements are rarely mentioned in [A, B] format, but usually [A  in the canton of B] etc.

[Expedia](https://www.expedia.co.uk/Lausanne.dx4474) includes the address

- Avenue de la Sallaz 8, Lausanne, Vaud

[AllTrails](https://www.alltrails.com/en-gb/switzerland/zurich/winterthur) offers

- [in] Winterthur, Zurich, Switzerland

[AllTrails](https://www.alltrails.com/en-gb/trail/germany/north-rhine-westphalia/rund-um-den-rhein-bei-bonn) also has, in Germany,

- [in] Bonn, North Rhine-Westphalia.

[Agoda.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Aesch%2C+Arlesheim%22&sca_esv=4874b8c2ba1eebb0&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=vFXPZZCFLe2BhbIPp5WTgAk&ved=0ahUKEwiQ0_zv7q-EAxXtQEEAHafKBJAQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22Aesch%2C+Arlesheim%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEiJBZXNjaCwgQXJsZXNoZWltIjIGEAAYBxgeMgsQABiABBiKBRiGA0iKMlDKB1iBLnABeACQAQCYAY4BoAGiA6oBAzQuMbgBA8gBAPgBAvgBAcICCRAAGAcYHhiwA8ICBxAuGB4YsAPCAgkQABgIGB4YsAPCAggQABiABBiiBIgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) uses two formats:

- Best Hotels in Aesch (Arlesheim) ...  Aesch, Arlesheim

[Shutterstock](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Bern%2C+Bern-Mittelland%22&sca_esv=4874b8c2ba1eebb0&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=W1fPZe35DYzAhbIPwM660AY&ved=0ahUKEwitk8-18K-EAxUMYEEAHUCnDmoQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22Bern%2C+Bern-Mittelland%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFyJCZXJuLCBCZXJuLU1pdHRlbGxhbmQiMgYQLhgHGB4yCBAAGAUYBxgeMgYQABgIGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeMgsQABiABBiKBRiGAzILEAAYgAQYigUYhgMyCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDMhUQLhgHGB4YlwUY3AQY3gQY4ATYAQFI9TFQ3QZYmS5wAXgAkAEAmAGTAaAB8wOqAQMzLjK4AQPIAQD4AQL4AQHCAgkQABgIGB4YsAPCAg4QABiABBiKBRiGAxiwA8ICCBAAGIAEGKIEiAYBkAYEugYGCAEQARgU&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) has:

- Bern, Bern-Mittelland/ Switzerland

But [Maptons](https://ng.maptons.com/89533) goes further, helping those unfamiliar with Swiss administrative divisions:

- [Where is] Aarburg, Zofingen District, Aargau, Switzerland

As does [TripAdvisor](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Bern%2C+Bern-Mittelland%22&sca_esv=4874b8c2ba1eebb0&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=W1fPZe35DYzAhbIPwM660AY&ved=0ahUKEwitk8-18K-EAxUMYEEAHUCnDmoQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22Bern%2C+Bern-Mittelland%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFyJCZXJuLCBCZXJuLU1pdHRlbGxhbmQiMgYQLhgHGB4yCBAAGAUYBxgeMgYQABgIGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeMgsQABiABBiKBRiGAzILEAAYgAQYigUYhgMyCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDMhUQLhgHGB4YlwUY3AQY3gQY4ATYAQFI9TFQ3QZYmS5wAXgAkAEAmAGTAaAB8wOqAQMzLjK4AQPIAQD4AQL4AQHCAgkQABgIGB4YsAPCAg4QABiABBiKBRiGAxiwA8ICCBAAGIAEGKIEiAYBkAYEugYGCAEQARgU&sclient=gws-wiz-serp):

- [Featured Images of] Bern, Bern Mittelland District

The bottom line is that it the exact format doesn't really matter provided you're clear and reasonable uncluttered.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking on euronews.com to try and find examples in news stories, but there isn't much. Places like Sion and Davos are generally referred to without a Canton name, but maybe an explanation of where they are e.g. "Morgins, a village in Valais". Switzerland probably isn't big enough to pose much problem, while a bigger country like the US has lots of cities sharing names (Springfield, Columbus, Columbia, Portland, Augusta, etc) so disambiguation is needed.

Comment: Good point.  I wonder if any of the > 2k municipalities are duplicated by name among the 26 cantons?

Comment: It seems that at least in some cases, the "city, canton" format has been adopted by English Wikipedia in contrast to its German counterpart with "city (CA)".  Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greifensee,_Z%C3%BCrich with https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greifensee_ZH for example.

Comment: Yes, it seems more usual. But this is a question of preferred style/s rather than than right or wrong; grammar doesn't apply (though nonsense permutations should obviously be avoided) to label formatting.

Comment: "New York, New York" sounds just as ludicrous to my ears as "Zurich, Zurich".

Comment: Over 350 000 000 raw Google hits for "New York, New York", Notso. A famous film, its theme song immortalised by Liza Minnelli, a famous Las Vegas hotel ... I'd say it's the only such example that many native speakers find natural-sounding through familiarity.